# Saved video to server from iPhone wont play back via URL in MPMovieVideoController

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have saved a video file at medium quality from the iPhone to Google App Engine. The video plays back fine on the web using the given URL.

http://www.getsplash.com/t/video/wa6Rbzq74WOB

This file will not play back on iPhone, I just get a black screen. I've been able to play other .mov sample files from the web just fine so its not the Objective-C as far as I know. I'm wondering if the encoding that the iPhone stores the video at is not compatible with pulling it back in via a URL?

I've tried adding an extension to the URL above and changing the content type to video/quicktime to no avail.

```
self.moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.getsplash.com/t/video/wa6Rbzq74WOB"]];
moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 51, 320, 240);
[scrollView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
[moviePlayerController play]
```

Comment: When testing that my hosted video is or isn't working I use this to make sure my objective-c code is working: http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_640x360.m4v

Comment: The code is working, I can run with other URLs. If I take my video from the above link (which was saved from the iPhone using Medium quality setting) and in Quicktime save it for playback on iPod/iPhone, then put it on the server, it works fine. I'm baffled that the video I save from the iPhone cannot play back on the iPhone from my URL. One would think ...

Answer (score 1):

Putting the answer here. The solution turned out to be adding ".m4v" to the end of the file URL and that enabled the MoviePlayerController to play it back. I thought relying on file extensions alone was a windows downfall, not something Apple relied on. We also ended up moving from Google Cloud Storage to AWS which has many more controls for types and security.

Answer (score 0):

What exact model of iPhone are you testing on?  The video is encoded with the Baseline 3.0 profile, which won't work on older models like the 3 and 3GS, I believe.

Comment: Testing on an iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s. The app is intended for 4 and above and iOS 5.0+